# Blender keeps Crashing on Chromebook

Tags: hardware

I have a chromebook that I installed crouton on (for those who don't know it just turns Chrome OS into a normal Linux System) and I tried using blender on it and it crashes after a few seconds even if I don't do anything.  I know this is likely due to the chromebook having a seriously weak processor but is there any way I can make blender less intensive so I can at least edit projects at all? Keep in mind I'm not asking to render that would be pure madness on that CPU.

Answer (score 1):

The slow processor will just cause blender to take longer to do things. It is more likely that the 2 or 4GB of RAM that most chromebooks have that would be the limiting factor, or opengl support.

You could try deleting (or moving temporarily) the addons folder, to see if the ram used by loading the addons helps.

If you start blender from a terminal you should see some indication of why it is crashing which might help.

To alter the resources needed to run blender you will need to [compile a version](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Building_Blender/Linux) yourself, there are some opengl options that may help, but in general I don't think there you will get any benefits if it can't startup, unless the issue is missing or incorrect library versions.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help! I'll be sure to try those out.